# Conditional Format on Cost deviations

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to find a way for a column to highlight when it is greater than a value pulled from a v look up formula. This is a cost deviations report for my business, so i would like the quoted cost (column H) to highlight red when the actual cost(AG) is found via the VLOOKUP function and is higher than the quoted cost.

thanks in advanced

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Apply this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule to range `H2:H`:

```
=H2 > AG2
```